# Excel read in HTML (eg. Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I want to read an excel file from an html page.
it can be via jquery or any other javascript code.
Unfortunately php is not an option for me now.

I don't want to just get a table as it is. I want to get any value from any cell.

I was using below code previously, but it doesn't work in chrome.

(also adding some extensions to chrome for using ActiveX is not option for me.)

```
    var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
    var excel_file = excel.Workbooks.Open("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/site/CampaignEntry2.xls");
    var excel_sheet = excel_file.Worksheets("Total");
```

I was able to bring data from any cell like this:

```
var data = excel_sheet.Cells(3, 4).Value;
```

Is there any solution like this but for all browsers?

Comment: This lib could do the job https://github.com/catamphetamine/read-excel-file

Comment: For a NodeJS/NPM solution there's this lib, which works with note just excel but pretty much any spreadsheet... https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx

Comment: @codeKonami as I understand this is parsing the excel sheet to json. but my excel sheet has more than 1 table and they have same titles, some empty columns and rows etc... because of that  I want to call my value from specific cell.

Comment: @Sam Clarke I need basic javacsript which will run in basic html. I know its very old logic but this is my case. this page will run in browser in a common pc which I'm not able to load any npm or something like that.

Comment: Some questions: (a) Will your code run only on the local machine, or does it need to work over a webserver? (b) If local machine: Can you install a framework like xampp on the local machine? (c) If local machine: Can you install python on local machine?

Comment: @gibberish it will work on the local machine. and I'm not able to load xampp or any other software. for now I'm using the example which I gave. but it works only in internet explorer. I just wondered is there any similar solution. But until now, all solutions I found is about "binding the table directly to html page" to bring specific cells in different places of the html is not an option.